# group by multiple files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have many files in many subdirectories, all files are comma delimited. I would like to group by first field in each file and run total record count

```
A = LOAD '/files/*' USING PigStorage(',') as (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = GROUP B BY f1;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT(f1) ;
DUMP D;
```

this code gives me me error

> Invalid field projection. Projected field [f1] does not exist in schema: group:chararray,A:bag{:tuple(f1:chararray,f2:bytearray,f3:bytearray,f4:bytearray,f5:bytearray)}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do a `GROUP BY ALL`

The problem is that you're trying to GROUP B by f1. f1 does not exist in B.

```
A = LOAD '/files/*' ...
B = GROUP A BY f1;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT(A);
DUMP C;
```

Try that.

Group by all is only used when you want to count the entire data set. Group by all should be used very carefully as all the data would be handled in a single reduce task if not careful.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT function takes the name of the BAG and not of the field. It should be:

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT(B) ;
```